# Stop condition for inverse power iteration

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods

Now I'm searching an eigenvector using existing eigenvalue approximation. But I'm unsure about when it's time to stop inverse power method iterations.

$b_k = (A-\lambda I)^{-1}*b_{k-1}$

Now I'm checking if $b_k$ is close enough to $b_{k-1}$, in other words if they have almost the same magnitude and direction. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: If $\lambda$ really is an eigenvalue, then $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}$ does not exist

Comment: But I have approximation of Lambda, not exact value of Lambda

Comment: @MaximVoloshin Yes, that is a reasonable stopping criterion.